# SharePoint 2010 Extended "What's New"/"Activity Feed" webpart

Tags: rss, activity-feed

I'm looking for a solution that will allow a site (by site I'll be refering to SPWebs) to dynamically subscribe to lists and libraries on subsites, and record additions, deletions, and updates of pages and other stuff of subsites. I can add feeds of most of these things manually using the RSS Viewer webpart, however there's management overhead if any content is added or deleted.

Does anybody know if a solution is already available or give me a head start if I need to develop a custom solution?

Comment: SharePoint Server/Enterprise?

Comment: Can you please explain the requirement little bit more. It will be really great if you can give an example.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if any available solution is already there...

About the custom solution.. What you can do is create a Event Receiver for lists and in that you can add new items to RSS Viewer WebPart or create a custom list on root site and add notifications as list item on that list...

You can put event receiver on ItemUpdating, ItemDeleting, ItemAdding and so on, have a look at this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252010.aspx

Inside an event receiver you have input parameter (SPItemEventProperties properties) which brings a lot of information like ListTitle, List etc, so you can make the notification more meaningful by adding list titles, item titles etc!

Hope this helps...